# Sakai connector portlet configuration

Tags: apache, liferay, tomcat7, sakai

I have installed sakai from the below link 
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/PLT/Sakai+Connector+Portlet+-+Configuration+and+Installation

I am facing problem in running imsblit/provider.
It is showing Basic LTI Provider is Disabled.
Please Help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enable Basic LTI](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/PLT/Sakai+Connector+Portlet+-+Configuration+and+Installation) by adding

```
basiclti.provider.enabled=true
```

to your `sakai.properties` or `local.properties`, then restarting Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Sakai LTI documentation:

https://github.com/sakaiproject/sakai/tree/master/basiclti/basiclti-docs/resources/docs

You will see a document called `sakai_basiclti_provider.doc` - it is the best source of information about the Sakai LTI Provider.